# how do you freeze/stop/apply a fire/smoke/fluid simulation?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

does anyone know? i found a video where they did it but it doesn't work anymore in blender 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its rather unclear what exactly you're looking into learning when youre not using complete sentences but if I'm hearing you right you'd like to learn how to control the 'time' of your fire simulations.

There basically two things that I'd recommend you to look into

1. The "Timescale" feature found in your fluid domain settings under the 'physics' tab. This directly controls the speed of your simulation: standardly set to 1.0 for realtime, a value of 0.25 would give you 25% speed on your simulation. The Value is animatable if you hover your cursor over the button and press <kbd>I</kbd> - Now you can do ramps in time and I hope that answers some of your questions.
2. If you're coming from an absolute beginners perspective and you wanna learn fire simulations from the start, then Youtube is your best and fastest tutor; take the time and carefully go end to end in this while following steps and you should know what you're looking for:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obxzidduhHk&ab_channel=Olav3DTutorials